# Constant current battery discharge

Tags: batteries, simulation, constant-current, discharge

I'm simulating NiMH cell discharge from 1.5V to 1.0V. The circuit I drew is supposed to draw a constant current from the battery.

[image: Circuit]

I simulate a DC Sweep in circuit lab but somehow the current draw is not constant. I get the following plot for the current draw from the battery.

[image: Plot]

Is there a problem with the schematic?
Can the schematic to draw constant-current be reduced to use less components?

EDIT: Also noticed a strange behavior of the simulation tool. I simulate another constant current circuit and do a DC sweep. Here is the [video](http://youtu.be/2Mu63I1Uvag)

---

EDIT (02062013):

Changed the transistors to 2n2222 and sense resistor.
[image: sch2]

Simulated again with same DC Sweep parameters. Notice the Y-Axis on this plot below.
[image: plot2]

Later simulated the same circuit in geda+gnucap+ngspice and plotted.

[[image]Click2Zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swieh.png)

Looks acceptable now :-)

Comment: I was going through the questions on transistors and happened to land up here. Could you tell me why you are using transistor Q2? A constant current source could have been created simply out of one single transistor, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 0.6V across R2, Vce on Q1 would vary from 0.9V down to 0.4V during your DC sweep. So you are operating Q1 very close to saturation and at the lower end you can't rely on its Hfe being much more than 10.

So Q1 is probably being starved of base current. You can try to improve its performance by reducing R1 to 220R.

But if you need more accuracy than that, I would suggest a rail-to-rail opamp sensing voltage across R3 (which should be somewhere around 2R to 5R) driving Q1.

Comment: As suggested, changing resistor value did not help much. Can you please add the opamp solution to your post. Perhaps adding a schematic would help.